# How to set Firefox (Dev Edition) as my default browser for npm start in React

Tags: reactjs, firefox

I want to use firefox with create-react-app start, but I keep when I follow the advice of adding.

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER='firefox' react-scripts start ",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

or (without quotes),

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER=firefox react-scripts start ",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

I get the error message:

```
'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So how would I specify the BROWSER variable in my package.json file? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Aren't you just asking how to set env vars in Windows? The CRA docs, amongst many other sources, include this information already.

Comment: You may have to install the cross-env package and then try